# Fluent hibernate and automapper inheritance

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, automapping

I have three entities:

```
BaseEntity (Guid Id) Primary key (for all entities)
Person (Name, FamilyName) : BaseEntity
Employee (Salary) : Person
```

How to map Employee so that its Primary key was also a foreign key for Person?

1. Should I inherit from Person in Employee class?
2. Or maybe I should both classes: Person and Employee inherits from BaseEntity
   and in Employee Add property: Person?

Anyway I was trying to achieve the first option. Is it possible?

EDIT

I am using auto mapper (FluentNHibernate.Automapping). 
I wanted here to achieve inheritance per type. That Both entities have their tables: Person (with Id, name, familyname) and Employee (id, salary)

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I meant that I am using FluentNHibernate.Automapping